# Namespace error when loading R package sjPlot

Tags: r, namespaces, loading, sjplot

I am getting this error when loading the R package sjPlot

library(sjPlot)
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'sjPlot':
'data_partition' object was not exported by 'namespace:parameters'

Somebody could help me.

Comment: You probably need to update the `parameters` package.  To update all your packages, run `update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)`.

Comment: Hi  user2554330,
In my case it seemed that the error was in the effectsize package. I reinstalled the whole easystats family of packages as well as the sj family. Everything is fine now. Thanks

Comment: I have already resintalled everything, but it won't work...any ideas @Cristiano  ?

Comment: I reinstalled everything