# Problem loading SjPlot after installing parameters

Tags: r, parameters, package, syntax-error, sjplot

I'm getting the [almost the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68308031/namespace-error-when-loading-r-package-sjplot) as the previous post, but the answers there are not working for me. I was able to use `sjPlot` with no issues until this afternoon when I installed `parameters` and `sandwich` and `clubsandwich`. I don't know what else I can do to get over this.

- the error:

```
> library(sjPlot)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sjPlot’:
 object ‘standard_error_robust’ was not exported by 'namespace:parameters'
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘sjPlot’ was built under R version 4.1.3
```

- Any help would be much appreciated. Updating `parameters` didn't solve it. Meanwhile, is there an equivalent function for `tab_model()?` (since I cannot use it...). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you updated `sjPlot` as well?

Comment: @stefan , yes :/

Comment: There is a related issue on GitHub with some instructions to fix the issue: https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/issues/866

Comment: @stefan hi, thanks, so I've tried strengejacke's solution there and it worked after running ```Run install.packages(c("sjstats", "sjPlot"))``` . Thing is, now whenever I run library(sjPlot) it advices me to load all sj packages, but that's ok (I didn't even know sjstats)

Comment: `sjPlot` **randomly** emits helpful package startup messages: see https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/blob/master/R/zzz.R

Answer (score 1):

devtools::install_github("strengejacke/sjPlot") worked for me :D